# How can I moderate users on an OSQA admin site?

Tags: django-admin, admin, osqa

I can't see any link in the OSQA admin site to moderate users accounts. How can this be done?

Comment: Moderate users meaning: 1. have a moderator approve a users posts before they appear, or 2. edit a users account?

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask this sort of question over on http://meta.osqa.net/ , where the OSQA specialists hang out.

In this case, to edit a user's account, log in as admin, then view your target user's profile, by clicking on their name on any of their questions or answers.

In the top-centre of the screen, in the line just below their name, you'll find "User Tools" with a drop-down menu, which allows you to edit their profile.

At the moment, AFAIK, there's no means to have a moderator approve a user's post before it appears.